# search query with join shows all rows when searched string is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have a query to search in two tables for a vacancy.

The variables for this query are send with a form that has multiple inputs/selects. One is a text input for the title of a vacancy and the other is a dropdown with all categories a vacancy can belong to.

When I leave the text input empty and select only a category, I get all vacancies not just the ones from the selected category.

My query:

```
$functie = $_POST['functie'];
$branche = $_POST['branche'];
$regio = $_POST['regio'];

$search = "
SELECT cnt.title, cnt.alias, cnt.images, cnt.introtext, cnt.catid, cat.title, cat.alias
FROM snm_content cnt
LEFT JOIN snm_categories cat
ON cat.id = cnt.catid
WHERE ('".$functie."' ='' OR cnt.title LIKE '%".$functie."%')
OR ('".$branche."' ='' OR cat.title LIKE '%".$branche."%')
";
```

If I echo the query without typing in the text input this is what I get:

```
SELECT cnt.title, cnt.alias, cnt.images, cnt.introtext, cnt.catid, cat.title, cat.alias
FROM snm_content cnt
LEFT JOIN snm_categories cat
ON cat.id = cnt.catid
WHERE ('' ='' OR cnt.title LIKE '%%')
OR ('logistiek' ='' OR cat.title LIKE '%logistiek%')
```

`snm_content` are the vacancies and `snm_categories` are the categories.

How can I show only the vacancies belonging to the category that was selected?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes I forgot, I'll accept now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note that** your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Now, we will need to generate the `WHERE` part of the query dynamically. We can use [`!empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function to check whether an input filter value is not empty, and then add its condition to the query dynamically.

```
$functie = $_POST['functie'];
$branche = $_POST['branche'];
$regio = $_POST['regio'];

$search = "
SELECT cnt.title, cnt.alias, cnt.images, cnt.introtext, cnt.catid, cat.title, cat.alias
FROM snm_content cnt
LEFT JOIN snm_categories cat
ON cat.id = cnt.catid ";

// Collect all the where conditions in an array
$whr = array();

// check if $functie has some value in input filter
if (!empty($functie)) {
    $whr[] = "cnt.title LIKE '%" . $functie . "%'";
}

// check if $branche has some value in input filter
if (!empty($branche)) {
    $whr[] = "cat.title LIKE '%" . $branche . "%'";
}

$where_sql = '';
// Prepare where part of the SQL
if (!empty($whr)) {

    $where_sql = ' WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $whr);
}

// Append to the original sql
$search .= $where_sql;
```